# Form inside while loop working on only the 1st result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a from inside of a while loop. I am processing it with ajax. Its working only on the first from and not on the other results. Please have a look.

```
<?php while($a = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mbs_id; ?>" class="memid">
        <select class="validity" class="upgrade-valsel">
            <?php while($mv = $mval->fetch()){ extract($mv); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $mv_id; ?>"><?php echo $mv_validity; if($mv_validity == 1){ echo " month"; }else{ echo " months"; } ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Upgrade" class="submit">
        <div class="center-align" style="margin-left: -20px"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="auto" id="loading-rent" style="margin-right: 0px; height: 40px"></div>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

When I click on submit button on the first result it process the result. But when I click on other buttons then its just refreshing the page. I tried replacing all the IDs with CLASS but after that not even the 1st one is working. Please help me.

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            memid: $(".memid").val(),
            validity: $(".validity").val()
        };
        $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to upgrade your membership to <?php echo $mbs_name; ?>?',
        buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType : "json",
                        url: "upgrade-process.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: true,
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $("#submit").hide();
                            $("#loading-rent").show();
                            $(".message").hide();
                        },
                        success: function(json){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                                $("#submit").show();
                                $("#loading-rent").hide();
                            },1000);
                        }
                    });
        },
        cancel: function () {
          $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
        }
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: it's because you are not using `$(this)`

Comment: where? can u explain further or right an answer?

Comment: js wouldn't know which which form/input you want to use, because `$(".memid")` returns all of them.

Comment: `$(".memid").val(),` will always pic first form value (same for other one). Again. Also  `$(".message")` and ` $("#loading-rent")` come individually for all forms or they are only one on hole page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alive to Die and Jeff try to explain it, you use selector which returns several objects so when you use a function on this set of objects, jquery only use the first object of this set.

You have to use "this" to work on the context :

```
$(".submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this) : your input with class .submit (the one you click)
    // parent() : the parent of $(this) (the form)
    // and then find the child with the unique class you want
    var dataString = {
        memid: $(this).parent().find(".memid").val(),
        validity: $(this).parent().find(".validity").val()
    };
    // EDIT: Get the loading image (you should use a class instead of this selector)
    var loader = $(this).parent().find("> div");
    // After you can use loader in this function and all sub functions
    loader.hide();
    // And then the rest of your code with the same logic...
});
```

Pay attention each function has a different $(this) linked to its execution context.

Comment: there is a loading image just after the submit button.. it should be displayed below that particular button which is clicked but its displayed on only below the button of 1st result no matter which button from which result is clicked... Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` to prevent the page from refreshing when you click the `submit` button. Use `this` to get the current form's values. Change your `dataString` to use `this` to get the values of the current form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = {
        memid: $(this).parent().find(".memid").val(),
        validity: $(this).parent().find(".validity").val()
    };
    $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to upgrade your membership to <?php echo $mbs_name; ?>?',
    buttons: {
    confirm: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType : "json",
                    url: "upgrade-process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: true,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#submit").hide();
                        $("#loading-rent").show();
                        $(".message").hide();
                    },
                    success: function(json){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                            $("#submit").show();
                            $("#loading-rent").hide();
                        },1000);
                    }
                });
    },
    cancel: function () {
      $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```